# Xdebug Error: "Failed loading xdebug.so: xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Tags: php, apache, debugging, xdebug, php-ini

I recently installed `xdebug` on my server but restricted it's use to our test site, which uses it's own `php.ini` file.

For example, the test sites `php.ini` is located at:

```
/home/test_site/public_html/subdomain_name/php.ini
```

Inside this `php.ini` file I have the below for xdebug:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so

xdebug.profiler_append = 0

xdebug.profiler_enable = 1

xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0

xdebug.profiler_output_dir = /home/test_site/xdebug

xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%s-%u.%h_%r"
```

Now, the thing is, xdebug **works** fine, no problems.

However, on our main site, which also has it's own `php.ini` file, which is located for example at:

```
/home/main_site/public_html/php.ini
```

Inside this file I have nothing for `xdebug` in there.

Now, I recently setup a cron in cpanel for the `main site` such as:

```
php -f /home/main_site/public_html/cron_jobs/main_cron.php > /home/main_site/public_html/logs/main_cron.log 2>&1
```

Now, upon checking the output of the cron inside the log file I get the output:

```
Failed loading xdebug.so:  xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Why am I getting this error when the main site shouldn't even be loading xdebug?

Comment: You might need to double check that the php-cli version that you're using to run the main_cron.php script isn't using the php.ini that has the xdebug configurations in it.  `php -i | grep xdebug` should show you.  Then, `php -i | grep php.ini` should show you which php.ini the php-cli is configured to use.

Comment: Please try `which php` to figure out the path of PHP version which is executing your script.

Comment: @dcarrith When I ran `php -i | grep xdebug` I got `Failed loading xdebug.so:  xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. When I ran `php -i | grep php.ini` I got the same error message as well as `Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/lib ... Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/lib/php.ini`

Comment: @KraneBird `/usr/local/bin/php`

Comment: @Brett - Have you checked the `/usr/local/lib/php.ini` to see if there is a `zend_extension=xdebug.so` in there somewhere?  You may just have to set the `extension_dir` to wherever xdebug.so is stored.  `sudo find / -name xdebug.so` to find it.  Then, restart Apache of course.

Comment: The important thing to take away from this is, CRON uses php-cli.  It looks like your php-cli is configured to use `/usr/local/lib/php.ini` as the configuration file.  I'm not sure why xdebug works for one site and not the other though.  This is at least a hint as to what might be happening.

Comment: @dcarrith I will check that out - but what I'm wondering is, why is it even looking for xdebug?

Comment: @dcarrith Ok, I checked and have these lines: `extension_dir = "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626"` and `zend_extension="xdebug.so"`; I searched for the correct path and it gave the same path that I use for xdebug that I have in the `php.ini` file that is on the site I am using it on where it is working.

Comment: @dcarrith I assume I can just comment out the `zend_extension="xdebug.so"` in that file?

Comment: @Brett - I was wrong when I said you might just have to set `extension_dir` since Xdebug needs the full path.  So, I would try two things to see what happens.  Try commenting it out to see if it breaks it on the site you want it working.  Then, try giving it an absolute path to see if it will at least get rid of the error.  `zend_extension = /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so`

Comment: See the docs where they put "full path" in bold print: http://www.xdebug.org/docs/install

Comment: @dcarrith Commenting it out worked - Error message is now gone and xdebug still works on that one site. :) Feel free to add your solution as an answer and you will get the bounty. :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Even though you have the two sites split up and using two different php.ini files, CRON will still use whichever php.ini file the PHP-CLI is configured to use.  So, to figure out which php.ini CRON is using, this is the command to use:

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

If PHP-CLI happens to be using a php.ini file that you didn't expect it to be using (such as `/usr/local/lib/php.ini`) then that will be the key to figuring out why you're seeing Xdebug errors in the logs.

It turns out that the `/usr/local/lib/php.ini` file had these two values set:

```
extension_dir = "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626"
zend_extension = "xdebug.so"
```

That was causing the error from the php script that was run by CRON (i.e. PHP-CLI) because zend_extensions need the full path to the module.  This is also stated in the Xdebug documentation: http://xdebug.org/docs/install

So, to get rid of the error, just comment out that line (or just remove it).  You could also comment out or remove the `extension_dir` line as long as you are not loading any other modules such as:

```
extension = memcached.so
```

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes might be difficult from where the XDebug library is loaded since it can be done either by specifying the path in php.ini or by adding the lib in mods-available.

Firstly, run:

```
$ sudo grep 'xdebug' -r /etc/php/*
```

This will give you the files that loads the extension.

Now identify which php.ini is in use:

```
$ php -i | grep php.ini
```

This will give you the php version in use (in case you have multiple php versions). Now link the php version with the result from the first step.

Now, either you have to comment out the line where the xdebug extension is loaded or remove the xdebug.ini file (that loads the extension) from /etc/php/x.x/mods-available (where x.x stands for the php version in use).

Comment: Thank you. For MacOS M1 with HomeBrew installed PHP: `sudo grep 'xdebug' -r /opt/homebrew/etc/php/*`

Answer (score 3):

I tried all the processes mentioned above and for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23408771/xdebug-error-failed-loading-xdebug-so-xdebug-so-cannot-open-shared-object-fi#answer-61152490) and many similar after Googling around, I still ended up with this error

```
$  php -i | grep php.ini
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20200930/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php/20200930/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: zend_get_properties_for
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/7.3/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini
```

I resolved this by **Updating Xdebug** using **Pecl**. If you do not have it installed following the instruction [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.intro.php)

```
$ pecl install xdebug
```

Now I changed my `xdebug.ini` file. You can use

```
$ locate xdebug.ini
```

Add `zend_extension = usr/lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so` to the file.

xdebug.ini

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = usr/lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so
```

The latest version of [**Xdebug 3.0.4**](https://xdebug.org/) still uses these `usr/lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so` but if you try to use `$ locate xdebug.so` you would see a different file location.

Php output the right Zend Extensions

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.3.27-9+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Feb 23 2021 15:10:08) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.27, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.27-9+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
```

Answer (score 2):

For the record, in Linux Mint and I think in some Ubuntu Systems. To change the php.ini it's the best to go to **/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d** and look for the xdebug.ini and you must change the lines said in the post above mine.

Answer (score 2):

I tried below in Linux and worked,

you can use the below command to locate the xdebug.so file path

```
locate xdebug.so

ex: /usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so
```

use below command to locate the current php.ini file

```
php -i | grep php.ini

ex: 

Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/7.1/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini
```

After that add below xdebug configuration to both cli and apache2 folder's php.ini files with correct xdebug.so file path.

```
vi /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini
vi /etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini

[xdebug]
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

Finally, restart the apache2 server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Make sure that you are using the correct xdebug port in your editor!

Cheers! :)